# Loop through rows and count based on table name

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is my database table:

```
Status
------
Active
Active
Inactive
Removed
Removed
```

My desired output:

```
Status   |  Total  | Percent
-------------------------------
Active   |    2    |  33.33   
Inactive |    1    |  16.66
Removed  |    3    |  50
Total    |    6    |  100
```

What i've attempted:

```
SELECT
    OrderStatus AS Status,
    COUNT(OrderStatus) AS Total,
    ROUND(((COUNT(OrderStatus ) * 100)/COUNT(*)),2) AS Percent
FROM
    myTable
```

For obvious reasons my query is not working, any help appreciated!

Comment: If access supports derived tables, such as `select * from (select field from table where 1 = 2 ) derivedTable` then that's the approach you should take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the group by clause, and you need to divide by the total number of records, which you can get with a subquery:

```
SELECT
    OrderStatus AS Status,
    COUNT(OrderStatus) AS Total,
    ROUND((COUNT(OrderStatus ) * 100)/(select COUNT(*) from myTable),2) AS [Percent]
FROM
    myTable
Group by OrderStatus
```

Comment: this will return 100 percent for all rows

Comment: Ah... I missed that issue with the original query.  Updated my answer.

Comment: @BrianPressler wouldn't you rather put the total count in a variable so that it doesn't need to be repeatedly calculated?

Comment: MS Access doesn't allow variables in SQL queries.

Comment: @BrianPressler aha!  I didn't see the ms-access tag.  Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the total records in the table to a variable.  This will prevent it from needing to be recalculated for each record.  A small issue with only 5 records, but if you ever applied this logic to a larger table with more unique values, the difference should become noticable.

**SQL:**

```
declare @TempTable table([OrderStatus] varchar(50))

insert into @TempTable
values
('Active'),
('Active'),
('Inactive'),
('Removed'),
('Removed')

DECLARE @TotalRecords int = (Select Count(*) from @TempTable)

SELECT
    OrderStatus AS Status,
    COUNT(OrderStatus) AS Total,
    ROUND((COUNT(OrderStatus ) * 100)/@TotalRecords,2) AS [Percent]
FROM
    @TempTable
Group by OrderStatus
```

**Results:**

```
(5 row(s) affected)
Status                                             Total       Percent
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- -----------
Active                                             2           40
Inactive                                           1           20
Removed                                            2           40

(3 row(s) affected)
```